# R split and get the sum of each group

Tags: r, split, sum

I am a beginner to R and I am stuck with a probably simple problem. I have a data frame `NEI_small` like that:

[image]

Now I want to calculate the sum of the emissions per year. So It should look like that:

```
 year  Emission
 1999  29920139
 2002  41757550
```

**How can I get the sum of a group ?**

I tried this but it didn`t work :

```
   sapply(split(NEI_small,NEI_small$year),sum(NEI_small$Emissions))
```

But I got this error :

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : 'sum(NEI_small$Emissions)' ist nicht
>   Funktion, Zeichen oder Symbol

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Try `aggregate(Emissions ~year, NEI_small, FUN = sum)`

Comment: Thank you that worked !!